# Custom defined routes not resolving in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel 5.2 instance utilizing all the typical out-of-the-box routes for dashboard, cases, home, login/logout, and users (which is working well). I now need to create a wizard with steps (step1, step2, step3, etc.), and I need access to the session. I assigned them to the group middleware.

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // Uses Web middleware
    });
    Route::get('wizard/step1', [
        'as' => 'wizard/step1', 'uses' => 'Wizard\WizardController@getStep1']);
    Route::get('wizard/step2', [
        'as' => 'wizard/step2', 'uses' => 'Wizard\WizardController@getStep2']);
});
```

However, when I go to the named route(s), I get a 404 error. So WizardController looks like the following.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Wizard;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;

class WizardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function getStep1()
    {
        return view('wizard.step1');
    }
}
```

The defined views are `resources/views/wizard/step1.php`. Ideally, I'd like to refactor it so that Wizard is a separate group. However, nothing seems to work with the way I'm defining custom routing currently.

Comment: The issue is with your middleware. You have quest middleware in your WizardController whereas in your router you're defining them to "auth"

Comment: what url are you trying to reach? would be important to know  ... also what named routes, you have no named routes in that example.

Comment: @lagbox: I'm trying to reach the url http://localhost/laravel-project/wizard/step1. I've added the named routes, please take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you cache the routes. The new route entries you add will never be recognized unless you clear the route cache.

You can delete cached routes using `php artisan route:clear`.

Since you will be changing the routes frequently in dev env, **It is always better to not perform route caching while in dev environment.**

You can do it by only running `artisan route:cache` as a post-deploy hook in Git, or just run it as a part of your Forge deploy process. So that every time you deploy your code in your server, your routes are cached automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by running the command:

**`php artisan route:clear`**

This lets Artisan delete your route cache and you can you can make sure routes are in sync.

Thanks for the help!